# The provisioning profile is banned

Tags: ios, xamarin, provisioning-profile

I currently have an inhouse iOS distribution provisioning profile setup in the apple developer portal. I am using Xamarin + Visual Studio on windows to create an IPA for OTA distribution using that provisioning profile. Everything went smoothly until I try to install the app via OTA on my iPad. I get an error message saying "Unable to Download App". I tried to track down the problem by looking at the device console with my iPad connected to my mac. I found a line that said "The provisioning profile is banned". I also tried deleting the old provisioning profile, and created a new one and repeated my previous steps. Nothing seemed to fix my problem.

Does anyone know what would cause this to happen and how I can resolve this issue?

EDIT 1: I created an ad hoc Provisioning profile to see if that was working. OTA ad hoc installation works fine on my registered devices and subsequent inhouse installation seems to be work for that particular device. However, I am still getting the same error on different devices that i didn't do ad hocinstall on. This isn't really ideal, as the whole point of inhouse distribution is being able to distribute my app's internally without having to register my devices in the developer portal. I also attempted to install the app via xcode, and got these error messages: "App installation failed There was an internal API error" and "App installation failed The provisioning profile is banned."

Comment: That looks like a `phonegap` issue, are you including that framework in your project?

Comment: I do not believe Xamarin uses phonegap, and I haven't referenced phonegap anywhere in my project. Also, I am able to create the IPA, but  can't seem to install the distributed IPA.

Comment: The only place that [error message](https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy/blob/965185831e39c0f1c300afcce3033933d66e7f16/src/ios-deploy/errors.h#L312) shows up that I could find is in the phonegap repo on Github, so I'm a bit perplexed.

Comment: Yeah I came across that one too, and there doesn't seem to be any information out there besides that... But I think the error came from Apple, as this appeared in the device debug console, during the OTA installation process.

Comment: Third party libraries also show debugging information in the console too — and grepping for that string in Xcode 9.2 (9C40b) returns nada.

Comment: If you look at your certificate and provisioning profile in the Apple developer portal, are they both valid?

Comment: The certificate expires in 2020 and my provisioning profile's status is "Active" with expiration date in 2019. So it should be valid. Also, I've been able to distribute my apps "adhoc", using a different provisioning profile, but with the same certificate.